# Video glitch NVIDIA (card: unknown)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, video

I have an ASUS desktop PC which is giving me an annoying [video glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3YHW.jpg)

If I check card model with lspci I get:

```
VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0de5 (rev a1)
```

Apparently my Ubuntu doesn't know exactly me NVIDIA graphics card model, could that be my problem? I currently have a nvidia GeForce GT 530 on my PC.

The driver I'm using is the "post-release updates". I've also tried the recommended ones, and while the issue didn't go away, the pc seemed a bit slower.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

i would say update to 310 drivers for nvidia.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-310`

Comment: Also if you're using unity, after a reboot it may be necessary to run these commands to make unity visible again
`dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` then `setsid unity`

Comment: I actually ended up erasing and reinstalling, because after installing a driver following some obscure tutorial, my pc was not booting up no more... thanks anyway! Not everything is allright!